# bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7

Tags: java

Tengo un proyecto en `Netbeans` que me da este error. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

> warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   1 warning

Comment: No es un error, es un warning: Es posible que estés usando clases o métodos marcados como *deprecated* en tu código

Answer (score 0):

Este problema viene por la versión de jdk que estas utilizando respecto a la versión de la plataforma. Comprueba primero que en las variables de entorno tienes correctamente configurado el [java_home](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=389:configurar-java-en-windows-variables-de-entorno-javahome-y-path-cu00610b&catid=68&Itemid=188).

Si lo tienes bien instalado, en esta [guia](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/new-javac-warning-for-setting-an-older-source-without-bootclasspath) te dicen la forma correcta de configurar el bootclasspath. Es un poco engorro, así que como alternativa yo te propondría utilizar una versión de jdk acorde a la plataforma, aunque sea anterior.